# SwiftUI: ViewModifier where content is a Shape

Tags: swift, struct, stroke, viewmodifier

The following code works fine.  So really, I’m good ... But I wanted to learn about ViewModifiers ... so my goal is to separate the non-changing stuff from the dynamic stuff to create a **.cardify()** custom modifier to call on the Shapes Views.

```swift
struct SetCard: View {
    
    let pips: Int
    let shape: SetCardShape
    let color: Color
    let shading: Double
    let isSelected: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                ForEach( 0..<pips ) { _ in
                    ZStack {
                        getShape(self.shape).opacity(self.shading).foregroundColor(self.color)
                        getShape(self.shape).stroke().foregroundColor(self.color)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding() // for shape in RoundedRect
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(lineWidth: isSelected ? 3.0 : 1.0).foregroundColor(.orange)
        }
        .scaleEffect(isSelected ? 0.60 : 1.0 )
        .padding() // for spacing between cards 
    }
}
```

Again, for academic/learning reasons, I wanted to simplify this struct, and use a custom modifier to convert the main content into a standard card.

The below code block **only works** when I comment out the second `content` line in the `Cardify` ViewModifier struct.  All cards that used filled shapes for the pips render just fine.  Cards that require the Shape to be stroked (i.e. not filled) need that second `content` in my `Cardify` ViewModifer to work.

The second content line produces the error:

Value of type Cardify.Content (aka. _ViewModifier_Content) has no member foregroundColor

commenting out .foregroundColor() generates the error:
Value of type Cardify.Content (aka. _ViewModifier_Content) has no member stroke

```swift
struct SetCardWithCardify: View {
    
    let pips: Int
    let shape: SetCardShape
    let color: Color
    let shading: Double
    let isSelected: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            getShape(shape)
            .modifier(Cardify(pips: pips, shape: shape, color: color, shading: shading, isSelected: isSelected))
        }
    .scaleEffect(isSelected ? 0.60 : 1.0 )
        .padding() // for spacing between cards 
    }
}


struct Cardify: ViewModifier {
    
    var pips: Int
    var shape: SetCardShape
    var color: Color
    var shading: Double
    var isSelected: Bool
    
    func body(content: Content)  -> some View {
    
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                ForEach( 0..<pips ) { _ in
                    ZStack {
                        content.opacity(self.shading).foregroundColor(self.color)
                        content.stroke().foregroundColor(self.color)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding() // for shape in RoundedRect
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).stroke(lineWidth: isSelected ? 3.0 : 1.0).foregroundColor(.orange)
        }
    }
}
```

Just in case this is important, the following code is the source of `getShape()` which is the source of `content` in the `Cardify` ViewModifier.

```swift
func getShape(_ shape: SetCardShape ) -> some Shape {
    switch shape {
    case .circle:
        return AnyShape( Circle() )
    case .diamond:
        return AnyShape( SetDiamond() )
    case .squiggle:
        return AnyShape( SetSquiggle() )
    }
}


struct AnyShape: Shape {
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        return _path(rect)
    }
    
    init<S: Shape>(_ wrapped: S) {
        _path = { rect in
            let path = wrapped.path(in: rect)
            return path
        }
    }
    private let _path: (CGRect) -> Path
}
```

Diamond() and Squiggle() are structs that conform to Shape protocol, properly returning a path from `func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path in those structs.

I have tried downcasting the second content line with:

`(content as! Shape).blah blah blah`
which generates the error:

Protocol Shape can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements.

I have also tried:

`(content as! Path)`

This doesn't generate any compile-time errors, but when executing it fails with the error:

There was a problem encountered while running, check your code for mistakes around this line. (indicating the second content line).

What can I do to allow the compiler to know the type of content this is so that stroke() and foregroundColor() will work ?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure that you can, but you can sort of approximate it using an extension on Shape:

```swift
extension Shape {
    func modified() -> some View {
        foregroundColor(Color.secondary.opacity(0.5))
    }
}

// Usage example
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Rectangle().modified()
            Capsule().modified()
        }
    }
}
```

However, unlike a view modifier you can't access the environment so it's somewhat limited.